# How to find and replace values of an interval in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

In this list, the value right after `4` is either greater or smaller than `4` itself. More specifically, the smaller value is always `1`. The values of the interval from that `1` to the next `1` are always less than `4`.

How can I find and replace the value of such an interval, for example as the following:

```
list_2 = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0, 0, 0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0]
```

`1, 2, 1` get replaced because the first `1` is right after and smaller than `4`. So the interval from that first `1` to the second `1` gets replaced.

Other values don't have to be `nan`, I just highlight the replacements. To be clear, if the value right after is greater than `4` we will skip it.

Comment: for something that non uniform, you probably need to just do a for loop

Comment: Why does `1, 2, 1` get replaced? Can you provide a few more examples? *The values of the interval from that 1 to the next 1 are always less than 4* would imply that you replace all ranges `[0, 4)`, right?

Comment: `1, 2, 1` get replaced because the first `1` is right after and smaller than `4`. So the interval from that first `1` to the second `1` gets replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my try to let numpy do most of the heavy lifting,
unfortunately I do resort to for loops at the end, hope someone can suggest and maybe edit for a better solution.

this is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
list_1 = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1])

modified_list_1 = np.append(list_1,1) # to always have a "next 1"

idx_of_4 = np.where(modified_list_1==4)[0]
idx_of_1 = np.where(modified_list_1==1)[0]

idx_of_4_followed_by_1 = np.intersect1d(idx_of_4, idx_of_1-1)

arr_slice_idx = [(start, np.min(idx_of_1[idx_of_1>(start+1)])) for start in idx_of_4_followed_by_1]

for start,end in arr_slice_idx:
  list_1[start+1:end+1] = 0

print(list_1)
```

I start off by finding the indices of `4`s followed by `1`s by using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`np.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html), which is vectorized and should work really fast
Unfortunately here I ran out of inspiration, and to find the "next `1`" that closes each range I used a regular (rather ugly) comprehension.

Then when I have the start and the end, I use them to slice the original array and set the value to `0`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I modified this bit `[idx_of_1>=(start+1)]` to account for the case when the last element is `4`.

Comment: In fact it should be as in the original solution, i.e., `[idx_of_1>(start+1)]` so that the second element is the next `1`. A `ValueError` pass will get around the problem with last element of 4.

Answer (score 1):

As an option:

```
for i in range(len(list_1)): # looking at all the elements in the list in order.
    if a[i]==4: # if the number with "i" index equals to "4"
        if a[i+1] > 4: # if the number after 4 is greater than 4
            a[i+1] == nan # the number after 4 equals "nan"
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
list2 = []
i = 0
while i != len(list1):
    if list1[i] == 4:
        list2.append("nan")
        if list1[i+1] > 4:
            list2.append("Superior to 4 after a 4")
            i+=1
        else:
            list2.append("nan")
            i+=1
    else:
        list2.append("nan")
    i += 1
print(list2)
```

The code isn't optimized, but will put "nan" if the corresponding value isn't superior to 4 after a 4, and will put "superior to 4 after a 4" if it is.